# How to extract an attribute from a json response using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, api

I am using the face++ API, I need to get an attribute from the first request(json_resp) to add it in the second one (json_resp2)

```
import requests

json_resp = requests.post( 'https://api-          us.faceplusplus.com/facepp/v3/detect',
          data  = { 'api_key' : 'api key' ,
          'api_secret' : 'api secret',
           'image_url'     : 'http://www.pick-health.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/happy-person.jpg' } )

print("Response : ", json_resp.text)
```

This request outputs:

> Response :  {"image_id": "0UqxdZ6b58TaAFxBiujyMA==", "request_id": "1523139597,9f47c376-481b-446f-9fa3-fb49e404437c", "time_used": 327, "faces": [{"face_rectangle": {"width": 126, "top": 130, "left": 261, "height": 126}, "face_token": "2da210ada488fb10b58cdd2cd9eb3801"}]}

I need to access the face_token to pass it to the second request:

```
json_resp2 = requests.post( 'https://api-us.faceplusplus.com/facepp/v3/face/analyze',
          data  = { 'api_key' : 'api key' ,
          'api_secret' : 'api secret',
           'face_tokens'     : 'json_resp.face_tokens',
           'return_landmark':0,
           'return_attributes':'emotion'} )

print("Response2 : ", json_resp2.text)
```

how can I do this please ?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the text string from the response object, you can use `json_resp.text`.  You can then use the `json` library to convert this into a `dict`, and then extract the field you want:

```
json_resp = requests.post(...) ## Your post request, as written above

node = json.loads(json_resp.text)
face_token = node['faces'][0]['face_token']
```

Here is the full code (using your snippets above):

```
import requests
import json


api_key = 'your api key'
api_secret = 'your api secret'

json_resp = requests.post(
    'https://api-us.faceplusplus.com/facepp/v3/detect',
    data = {
        'api_key'    : api_key,
        'api_secret' : api_secret,
        'image_url'  : 'http://www.pick-health.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/happy-person.jpg'
    }
)

node = json.loads(json_resp.text)
face_token = node['faces'][0]['face_token']

json_resp2 = requests.post(
    'https://api-us.faceplusplus.com/facepp/v3/face/analyze',
    data  = {
        'api_key'           : api_key,
        'api_secret'        : api_secret,
        'face_tokens'       : face_token,
        'return_landmark'   : 0,
        'return_attributes' : 'emotion'
    }
)

print("Response2 : ", json_resp2.text)
```

PS: It's a bad idea to post API keys online, since people can run your bill up by using your services.